# How to make 18 from 1, 3, 4, 8

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle, formation-of-numbers

This question was on my sister's 5th-grade homework, practicing order of operations. It was to make 18, using the numbers 1, 3, 4, 8 and the operations +, -, and *. The instructions imply using each operation only once. Additionally, grouping with parenthesis is allowed.

Neither my sister, my father, or I were able to find a solution. I even tried writing a python script to attempt all possible solutions to the problem, to no avail.

Can you do what we can't? Or is the problem flawed?

Edit: Here is a picture of the original worksheet. The problem in question is #11. I assume that operations are only allowed once, because some of the other problems have an operation repeated, and because it refers to rearranging operations and numbers on a mat.
[image: A photo of the original worksheet]

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE! I have a few questions - 1. Can the order of the numbers be changed? 2. Did you omit division on purpose or by accident? 3. Are there any other allowed operators (concatenation, exponents, roots, etc.

Comment: @Brandon_J, Order of numbers can be changed. Division and other operations intentionally omitted.

Comment: @ferret I've updated the question with the original worksheet.

Comment: I suspect that the teacher either meant 16 or 17, as both are possible.

Comment: I suspected that from the beginning, but I have seen y'all solve some pretty dang hard puzzles, so I gave it a shot here.

Comment: I think I can even get 19 and 20 to work as well....but 18 haha.

Comment: Do we have an update yet?

Comment: I just added an answer. It was, in fact, a typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I had suspected, the teacher confirmed that the question was incorrect, and there is no correct answer.
Thank you all for the attempts.

Answer (score 2):

Here it is.....

> $18 * (4-3) = 18$

Comment: This works if concatenation is allowed. Considering it's a question for 5th graders, I doubt there is a "trick" like this, so I'm thinking it's a mistake by the teacher

Comment: I agree with ferret. It is highly unlikely that concatenation is allowed, given the circumstances.

Comment: See, for example, problems five, six, and nine. If concatenation were allowed, there would be no need to join the digits of the 2-digit numbers together.

Comment: @Brandon_J and ferret, you are both probably right. Let's wait for the teacher's explanation :-)

Comment: Yeah. Feel kinda bad for the teacher, tbh - I'm sure she'll feel bad for all the people that spent so much time on this.